# post the file on the server while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, php

While uploading the submit.php page, the file ankr1000.18d.Z that appears in dizin.png image is wanted to be added to file section
and automatically to be pressed "Submit to PPP" button  and send the file 
So what I want is to post the file on the server while the page is loading.
It needs to be done using the PHP language. I tried with Curl but I couldn't. I would be glad if you helped.

[image]

```
<form id="pppform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/CSRS-PPP/service/submit">
    <input aria-labelledby="rfilelabel" type="file" id="rfile_upload" name="rfile_upload" required aria-required="true" class="form-control">
    <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit to PPP">
</form>
```

Comment: use ajax, not CURL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to load file form users computer and send it to the server without user explicit action. If you are asking about that.